# NodeJS - 'database.getOneWhere' is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make global database functions, but everytime I try to access them it always says that the object is undefined, and I can't figure out why.

controllers/api/v1/users/index.js:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var database = require(path.resolve('database'));

module.exports = function (router) {
    router.put('/', function (req, res) {
        database.getOneWhere('table', 'row', 'data').then(result => {
            //
        });
    });
}
```

database/index.js:

```
'use strict';

const r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports = async function() {
    getOneWhere = async function(table, key, value, callback) {
        let conn = await r.connect({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 28015});
        let cursor = await r.db('table').table(table).filter(r.row(key).eq(value)).run(conn);

        try {
            let arr = await cursor.toArray();
            callback(arr);
        } catch(e) {
            callback(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It always says that `database.getOneWhere` is not a function. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOneWhere` should be a property of `module.exports`. You defined `module.exports` as a function and put `getOneWhere` within that though. It should be:

```
'use strict';

const r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports = {
    getOneWhere: async function(table, key, value, callback) {
        let conn = await r.connect({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 28015});
        let cursor = await r.db('table').table(table).filter(r.row(key).eq(value)).run(conn);

        try {
            let arr = await cursor.toArray();
            callback(arr);
        } catch(e) {
            callback(e);
        }
    }
};
```

Or alternatively:

```
'use strict';

const r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports.getOneWhere = async function(table, key, value, callback) {
    let conn = await r.connect({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 28015});
    let cursor = await r.db('table').table(table).filter(r.row(key).eq(value)).run(conn);

    try {
        let arr = await cursor.toArray();
        callback(arr);
    } catch(e) {
        callback(e);
    }
};
```